# What's wrong with transferring $12,000 from RRSP to RRIF and withdraw $2000/yr 65-71 inclusive? Why doesn't this give you $12000 out RRSP tax-free?

Tags: income-tax, canada, withdrawal, rrsp, tax-credit

I live in ON. [Jim Yih](https://www.clearpointbenefits.com/team/) wrote [Are You Taking Advantage of the Pension Income Tax Credit?](https://retirehappy.ca/are-you-taking-advantage-of-the-pension/)

> **Transfer RRSP to a RRIF**. At age 65 transfer $12,000 to a RRIF and take $2000 out per year from age 65 to 71(inclusive). This essentially allows you to get $2000 out of your RRSP tax-free for 6 years. Whether you need the income or not, it is an opportunity you do not want to miss.

But [hydraSlav](https://redd.it/dllzu1) and [aughhhhh](https://old.reddit.com/r/PersonalFinanceCanada/comments/9t16qc/pension_income_tax_credit/e8t0l40/) say Jim Yih is wrong. Why? Pls ELI5.